# Best way to authenticate application to use AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

lets say I have a on-premise application that needs to access various AWS services such as S3, Cloudwatch etc. What is the correct way to handle this authentication? I have read recommendations to create a new iam role and then distribute the AWS keys on the server that the application runs. But wouldn't this be very bad practice in case the keys gets stolen or exposed in some way? It would also be more work to rotate credentials for example. Is it possible to assign roles in some other ways or this is the correct way to do it? Isn't it better to assign roles or that isn't possible when not running the app in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, your application can use one set of credentials to get another, more privileged set of credentials. The app must be able to authenticate somehow so it needs some basic form of service account credentials to start with.

One way you can do this is to create an IAM user with minimal privileges. This IAM user is able to assume a specific IAM service role, but nothing else. That service role actually confers permissions to interact with S3, CloudWatch etc. Your application is configured with, or somehow securely retrieves, the credentials associated with the IAM user. Your application then uses these to call STS and assume the IAM service role, getting back short-lived STS credentials (access key, secret key, and session token). You should leverage the additional 'external ID' with the IAM role, as one more security factor.

Your application is also responsible for getting a new set of credentials before the existing set expires. You can do that in a number of ways, for example by using new STS credentials for every single request you make (so they never expire) or simply paying attention to the credentials expiration time and refreshing prior.

Also, read [Temporary Credentials for Users in Untrusted Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#api_getsessiontoken).

Answer (score 0):

Creat an IAM user with “Programmatic Access” only, which will provide you with a key and secret pair.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance and it is the only application on that instance, then:

- Create an IAM Role
- Assign the appropriate permissions to the Role
- Assign the IAM Role to the EC2 instance
- Any software running on the instance will automatically have access to credentials to access AWS. These credentials automatically rotate every 6 hours.

If you are *not* running on an EC2 instance:

- Create an IAM User
- Assign the appropriate permissions to the User
- Generate credentials for the User (Access Key, Secret Key) and store them in a credentials file on the computer being used by the application
- Any software running on the instance will automatically have access to these credentials to access AWS.

Comment: Inside AWS => role, outside AWS => credential (Idp, file...)